# Why is my Entity Framework test failing?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, testing, amazon-web-services

I followed [this tutorial](https://techjukebox.wordpress.com/2013/06/27/entity-framework-code-first-with-aws-sql-rds/) to create an AWS RDS SQL Server database for use with Entity Framework 6.

I have created an RDS instance in Visual Studio 2013 AWS Explorer, and added the connection string in `Web.config` as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add 
    name="SystemDBContext"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=dataSourceAddress,1433;Initial Catalog=instanceName;User ID=userID;Password=password"
  />
</connectionStrings>
```

This test that checks I can open a connection is failing:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestSystemDb()
    {
        TestConnection();  
    }

    private void TestConnection()
    {
        using (var db = new SystemDBContext())
        {
            var conn = db.Database.Connection;
            conn.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Test method BabyChangeFinder.Tests.DatabaseTest.TestSystemDb threw exception: 

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "BabyChangeFinder.DataAccess.SystemDBContext" requested by the login. The login failed.

Login failed for user 'RIG\Nick'.
    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, ref Boolean dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, ref DbConnectionInternal connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, ref DbConnectionInternal connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, ref DbConnectionInternal connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at BabyChangeFinder.Tests.DatabaseTest.TestConnection() in DatabaseTest.cs: line 23
   at BabyChangeFinder.Tests.DatabaseTest.TestSystemDb() in DatabaseTest.cs: line 13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the connection cannot be established for some reason. You would have seen the detailed exception hapening at the connection establishing process instead of the AssertFailedException if you did not wrap the TestConnection method with try/catch. It´s a pretty good example of how NOT to use exception handling! 
Just remove it and run the test again.

```
private void TestConnection()
{
    using (var db = new SystemDBContext())
    {
        var conn = db.Database.Connection;           
        conn.Open();
    }
}
```

EDIT: You have written down the stack trace of the exception in that exception handler. You may also try to write down e.Message, as this is the exception text you surely wanted to see, but this message should also be visible in the test results when the test is failing...

Comment: You haven't really answered my question or given me a decent idea of what to do - my TestConnection returned a bool so if I just make the change you suggested (ie make TestConnection void) the test will not then work. Btw I am quite new to this - please be more specific.

Comment: Noone can help you unless the exception message is more specific, that was what i was trying to say. The test should now give you a more detailed exception instead of "result was not true". What is the exception you are getting now?

Comment: Ah, good! So, the login is failing. You surely already checked wether the correct credentials were supplied via the connection  string?